# How to prevent bash shell in Windows from exiting?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, virtualenv

I am calling a bash shell scripts in Windows by double click using association of the the extension.  The problem is that the shell exits immediately unless a blocking call is made.  This script exits immediately after setting up some environment variables by calling an "activate" sub-script file, but I want it to not exit and be available for interactive use:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

I have tried calling bash hoping that the environment would be passed, but the environment was either not passed, or passed and then re-intialized - although the resulting shell **was** available for interactive use:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
/bin/bash
```

Notably, the script

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
python app.py
```

will make the environment set up by "activate" available to the "python app.py" call.

Comment: Maybe, as Microsoft has apparently gone all FOSS-friendly and given poor Windows users a decent shell at last (`bash`), maybe they will ship `expect` too which would do what you want using its `interact` feature.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Thanks for the lead.  As it happens, I'm on wondows 7 and this is the bash.exe shell which comes with the Git release for windows: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe .